# PHP code snippet decode

Tags: php

I was looking a craigslist for web dev jobs (I am a beginner).
I came across a Jr. job that wanted me to decode this snippet.

```
 <?php 
 $f1  = 'e' . 'x' . 'p';
 $f1 .= 'l' . 'o' . 'd' . 'e';

 list($f2,$ext) = $f1('.',$argv[0]);

  $x = array('a','H','I',
         'r','Y','2',
         'x','q','c',
         'm','R','l',
         'd','k','B',
         'l','d','m',
         '9','r','b',
         'm','93','L',
         'm','N','v',
         'b','Q','');
  echo $f2(implode('', $x)) . "\n";
  ?>
```

Since I do not know the answer I a a bad candidate for the job, but I would like to understand it if anyone can help me.  What I do get is that you are using the string of `$f1` to manipulate the array `$x`.  But i see problems with using `$argv[0]` and I believe that using `f2(implode('', $x))` will give a parameter error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was the request for 'fix' this snippet or interpret it?  Seems to need a lot of fixing to me

Comment: Looks like this is a basic code test put forth by the employer. Was that employer evoknow.com?

Comment: He acknowledged he is not the right candidate.  I approve of taking the time to learn / figure it out.

Comment: So it is bad code; forgetting about the list stuff I just cannot see how that explode function could work. It seems that they want me to change each character in the array by multiplying it but doing after an implode would give you 0.

Comment: `$argv[0]` is the name of the file, `$f1` = "explode", calling explode by `.` on the filename (maybe `test.php`) results in the name of the file, then the extension as separate vars. `$f2` becomes the name of the file (test), and `$ext` is the file exstension (php). Maybe if you named the file "base64_decode.php" before running it...

Comment: Yeah, I'll stick to fizzbuzz when we interview here.  Honestly this is pretty silly code.  Not having seen the original question I'm not really clear what they are looking for.  Want to see a fun backdoor... here I'll append it to the answer...

Comment: @castis ++ Well done.  That must be it.  Was wondering why the `argv[0]` wanted a `.`.  Doh.  Woodchuck.  Your new lesson.  Write the same thing substituting `base64_decode` for `str_rot13` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hehe, that was kidna fun.  It's the email to their HR department.

```
<?php 
$argv[0] = 'base64_decode.';

 $f1 = 'explode';

 list($f2,$ext) = $f1('.',$argv[0]);

  $x = array('a','H','I',
         'r','Y','2',
         'x','q','c',
         'm','R','l',
         'd','k','B',
         'l','d','m',
         '9','r','b',
         'm','93','L',
         'm','N','v',
         'b','Q','');
  echo $f2(implode('', $x)) . "\n";
```

Not really sure what they were looking for in an answer.  Made me think of this though.  http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/09/ask-sucuri-non-alphanumeric-backdoors.html